# Krusader: How to hide FN key bar permanently

Tags: kde, filemanager, krusader

Does anyone know how to hide **FN key bar** in Krusader so the settings are saved when it is restarted?

If you go to `Settings->Show FN key bars` and uncheck it, then FN bar disappears but only for the current session, meaning that if you quit Krusader and then it's shown again upon the start (this setting is not saved).

Maybe I could add some property to config file manually? Something like

```
Hide FN Keys=yes
```

But is there a key like this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Krusader settings**

Two ways:

1) Krusader > Settings > Configure Krusader > User Interface: Show function keys (on/off)

2) Krusader > Settings > Configure Krusader > User Interface: Save settings on exit and then Settings: Show FN key bars (on/off)

Comment: I can't believe I've missed it!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you happen to know, if it's possible to hide tabstop headers completely? I mean the bar of sorting features, right below Media Button? I just prefer using hotkeys for that purpose!

Comment: And maybe this, please: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330292/krusader-how-to-organize-available-media-list-mounted-drives